# Difference Between Splitting Field of a Polynomial and Extension Field Generated by roots

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I don´t understand if there is a difference between the two concepts of

1. Splitting Field of a Polynomial
2. Extension Field Generated by roots of the Polynomial.

I know that given a polynomial $ p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ the Splitting Field of p is a extension field over $ \mathbb{F} $ in wich the polynomial p splits in linear factors.

On the other hand, I Know that if we have the roots of $ p(x) $, then we can form the extension field generated by the roots that includes $ \mathbb{F}$, so for example, if the roots of $ p(x) $  are $r_1, r_2 $ and $ r_3$ then we can form $ \mathbb{F}[r_1, r_2, r_3]$ wich is a extension field over $ \mathbb{F}$  generated by the roots of the polynomial.

By the way, is so clearly that the Splitting Field of $ p(x) $ is included (as subset) in $ \mathbb{F}[r_1, r_2, r_3]$ , but, is there any difference between the Splitting Field of $ p(x) $ and $ \mathbb{F}[r_1, r_2, r_3]$  ?

Is (the Splitting Field of a Polynomial $ p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$) = (The extension Field over $ \mathbb{F}$ generated by the roots of $p(x) $) ?

Comment: One point you might think about is what it means to say "the roots are $r_1,r_2$, and $r_3$".  For instance. what are the roots of $x^7+x^3+x+1 \in {\mathbb F}_2[x]$? Where do they live? The case where ${\mathbb F} = \mathbb R$ can be misleading since we know that all polynomials in ${\mathbb R}[x]$ havve roots in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The problem is "the extension field generated by the roots" doesn't make sense. Where are those roots? In order to find the roots one needs to construct a field where they live. That's part of the deal with the splitting field. If you have a field $K$ and a polynomial $P(x) \in K[x]$ and you have a field $L$ in which $P(x)$ splits completely then the subfield of $L$ "generated by the roots" is indeed isomorphic to the splitting field.

Comment: I understand by "the extension field generated by the roots", the minimal extension field over the field $ \mathbb F $ wich includes all  the elements in $\mathbb F $ and the roots of the polynomial ( $r_1, r_2 $ and $ r_3$, for example ), I denote this by $ \mathbb{F}[r_1, r_2, r_3]$ and is minimal in the sense that  any other extension field over $ \mathbb{F}$ wich includes $r_1, r_2 $ and $ r_3$ also includes $ \mathbb{F}[r_1, r_2, r_3]$

Comment: Once again "the roots of the polynomial" does not make sense until you prove that such a field exists. You can't just "let" the roots be $r_1,r_2,r_3$.